# Regex match word and \n literally

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string.

```
const str = "This is a test.\n\nAnother Sentence.\nHello!";
```

I want the result

```
// ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test.', '\n', '\n', 'Another', 'Sentence.', '\n', 'Hello!']
```

I'm doing

```
const arr = str.match(/\w+/g);
// ["This", "is", "a", "test", "Another", "Sentence", "Hello"]
```

What should I do to include all the special characters like (.) and (!) etc and '\n' too in my result? Could you please help?

Comment: You can try with **[\w\.\\n!]+**, but you need to know all special characters that you want to include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
/\S+|\n/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/opnv72/1). It matches 1+ non-whitespace chars or a newline char, as many times as there are such chunks in the input string (due to `g` modifier).

JS demo:

```js
var str = "This is a test.\n\nAnother Sentence.\nHello!";
console.log(str.match(/\S+|\n/g));
```

Comment: *What should I do to include all the special characters like (.) and (!) etc and '\n' too in my result? ...* what to do so these special chars can also be treated as separate results ? Thanks.

Comment: @ths if you want separate results, learn more about regex capturing groups

Comment: @ths That is not what OP needs, see the expected result: `['This', 'is', 'a', 'test.', '\n', '\n', 'Another', 'Sentence.', '\n', 'Hello!']`. Of course, `str.match(/\w+|\W/g)` or `str.match(/\w+|\W+/g)` would tokenize it more.

Comment: You could make the expression a non capturing group using `?:`. EG: `(?:\S+|\n)` this will make it match but not capture the resulting group giving you the results you want.

Comment: @ug_ No need for a non-capturing group. `/(?:a|b)/` = `/a|b/`.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I don't mean to be unkind or something but I do know how to solve this but I saw the OP's last line on his post so I asked  @WiktorStribiżew for, let's say, a deeper answer (as he (@WiktorStribiżew ) seems to be way more familiar with regex than me) seeking to get a better solution than the one on my mind.